# Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX window

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to develop a web app where login form will appear in a RadWindow, which will slide from top and on close will go to top again. I have read many resouces but it's Animation property doesn't work like this. Do you have any experience with. What should I do? Please answer with some online example too. Thanks

Comment: Start posting your code if you need help and concerning demo look at Telerik resources on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, they do not work like that. So, it would be easiest if you **animate the control's popup element yourself**.

You can start with the **FlyIn** **animation** (it may be suitable for you, so you may not need to animate the appearance)

Then, you can use the **OnClientBeforeClose** event to **animate the popup away yourself** (there are many libraries that can do this for you and you can even use CSS animations), then hide it.

A similar approach is shown here http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/close-radwindow-with-resize-animation-instead-of-fade